# How to create a rectangular mesh using cgal?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I am currently trying to create a 2D rod. So its basically a rectangle with length and breadth.
Now I want to mesh this rectangle using triangle and squares (or small rectangle).

I was trying to achieve this task using cgal. I know we can do this using `CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2` for generating triangular mesh. But I was trying to find mesh in cgal that
could generate square (or rectangle) mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some maybe interesting pointers:

- [`make_hexahedron()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#gad9df350e98780f0c213046d8a257358e)
- [`extrude_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html#ga102e1ba5d709c5e53e013160792e4d08)
- [`isotropic_remeshing()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html#gad3d03890515ae8103bd32a30a3486412)

Comment: I was wondering how I could extract face information after I use make_hexahedron.

Comment: I asked this quesion here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819689/how-to-extract-face-information-from-linear-cell-complex-for-combinatorial-map-i)